# limit of general solutions of IVPs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Intial value problems are sometimes quite interesting well i came across one where you are to let $y($t) be the solution of the IVP **$y''$ +$y'$-2$y$=$0$** ,with conditions **$y$($0)=$b, $y'$($0$)=$2$**
You are tasked to find the value of **$b$** for which the **$$\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t)=0$$**

Well started by forming axilliary equation in the form $m^2$+$m$-$2$=$0$

I went through the necessary steps thus by using the general solution to find its first derivative and pluggining the intial value conditions and solving them simultaneously to find get a  for $b$ but i got stuck at the point in finding the value of b i had two values that will make the limit to infinity of the function zero but yet again I'm not getting it since it says one value.Is it that am wrong or something is not right

Comment: but apparently my y(t) = \dfrac{1}{3} (b-2) e^{-2 t}+\dfrac{2}{3} (b+1) e^t  was this where am i wrong though @Moo

Comment: Didn't get that I'm so confused can elaborate more on your solution

Comment: It seems that $$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{3} (b-2) e^{-2 t}+\dfrac{2}{3} (b+1) e^t$$ is correct.

Comment: Please add further essential insights like the complete solution formula (and indicate if and how you calculated this or if that is the reference solution) to the question text, not or not only in the comments.

Comment: Yeah Lutz I was finding it difficult to type due some technical hitches on my device. But my main concern is how to find the limit

Answer (score 1):

From the auxiliary equation

$$m^2 + m - 2 = 0 \implies m_{1, 2} = -2, 1$$

We can write the general solution as

$$\tag 1 y(t) = c_1 e^{-2t} + c_2 e^t$$

The derivative of $(1)$ is

$$\tag 2 y'(t) = -2 c_1 e^{-2t}  + c_2e^t$$

From the initial conditions

$$y(0) = c_1  + c_2  = b\\ y'(0) = -2c_1 + c_2 = 2$$

Now solve for those constants

$$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{3} b e^{-2 t}+\dfrac{2 b e^t}{3}-\dfrac{2 e^{-2 t}}{3}+\dfrac{2 e^t}{3}$$

Notice that the two negative exponents are not an issue in the limit, so we want to find $b$ such that the limit of the following is zero

$$\dfrac{2 b e^t}{3}+\dfrac{2 e^t}{3}$$

What does $b$ need to be because of the positive exponent?

Comment: Wow that's a great insight so just need the the relation above to get the limit

Comment: Because the exponential goes to infinity, what does $b$ need to be to make sure that doesn't happen?

Comment: Hello there, Moo!  Saw you in the review queue, having cast a "late answer" review.  Hope all is well!

Comment: Good to hear!  Yes, I am faring well and am staying safe.  We need to catch up some time!!

Comment: Well, since the spring semester ended, the close review queue is half the size it became under COVID this past semester!  Yes, I think I still have your email! ;-)